# GeoPandas: Calculate distance between list of points and a country and output result in kilometers

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to calculate the shortest distance between a polygon and a list of points. For this example I'm using the natural earth datasets for world and cities.

I have written the below code however the output is a distance in degree of coordinates and not in km. Please advise how to edit code to get km.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))


d=[]


#iam using geometry number [3] which is Canada.
for i in cities.geometry:

    z=i.distance(world.geometry[3])
    d.append(z)

print(d)
```

Also: Presumably the output of [z=i.distance(world.geometry[3])] is the shortest distance between point and polygon (not distance between centroid of polygon and point). Please let me know if its otherwise.

Comment: have you looked at the geopandas docs about reprojecting data? what didn't you understand about them? as for your last question -- you can figure that out yourself with a simple test case like a unit circle and a point a few meters away.

Comment: thanks. any other suggestions?

Comment: @PaulH points you in a correct place. You need to re-project your data (https://geopandas.org/projections.html). And yes, it is the shortest distance between point and polygon.

Comment: @TheOracle replace your example of complicated world and city data with simple geometric data so that you'll be able to reason about the correctness of everything first

Comment: Thanks guys I got it to work by changing crs to a km coordinate reference system

Comment: heres the code including crs used:   world=world.to_crs(epsg=32662)
cities=cities.to_crs(epsg=32662)

Comment: Such kind of question is more suited for [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).